# How to set if condition A then format X, if condition A and B then format Y?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

On Google Sheets I put conditional format:

Condition 1: `=IF(I2="Shipment (Pickup)",TRUE,FALSE)`

then background green, text None (or Black).

Condition 2:  `=AND(G2<(Now()+(16/24)),I2="Shipment (Pickup)")`

then background green, text RED

but it won't change as expected and only show the first condition when satisfied. If I delete the first one then the second one works.

How could I have both of them work?

Comment: Can you please post your entire code snippet? I believe the problem is the order of your conditions, but it'd help if I could see the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, it's just in the wrong order.

Make sure your first rule is:

```
=AND(G2<(Now()+(16/24)),I2="Shipment (Pickup)")
```

And the second rule is:

```
=IF(I2="Shipment (Pickup)",TRUE,FALSE)
```

You can change the order of your conditional formatting rules by clicking on the three dots on the left of the rules and dragging them around.

Here's a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1slVA2HoE0xxGXytwgPVJPnQBuM17s8jqcfd63kxbejE/edit?usp=sharing) to a Google Spreadsheet which does exactly that.

Comment: You are the best ! Thank you ! just add it for some one who doesn't know how to drag: click and hold the three dot on the left of the condition cell.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I just added this to the answer.

Comment: Hi @badermart : since you are very good on this google sheet, do you think you can have me with this question also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54300970/how-to-sum-up-the-values-in-each-column-and-ranking-each-column-name-by-sum-of-v